# Armv7: return frome exception to Thumb Code

Tags: arm, thumb

since I have no luck with my question on arm community (see [here](https://community.arm.com/thread/11000)), I also ask you the following question.

I am writing a OS targeted to ARM v7 processors, and I load executable in ELF32 format. If the LSB of the entry point address is set, it means that the entry point should be executed in Thumb mode. My question is to know whether a `movs pc, lr` will update the `CPSR.T` bit if the LSB of `lr` is set, or if I should first set `SPSR.T` bit by hand prior to performing my return from exception using `movs pc, lr`.

EDIT:
to be 100% clear, my question is about the very first scheduling of an application which entry point is in Thumb. There is no "old state" to return to.

Comment: Think about it - the SPSR is a saved copy of whatever the CPSR was at the time the exception happened, so why would restoring it not return everything to the exact same state? Also consider how a general exception handler, if it were supposed to set SPSR.T itself, could possibly know whether its exception was taken from Thumb or ARM state, and thus what to set it to...

Comment: I completely agree, but my point is about the very first time the process is scheduled: there is not "old state" so I have to forge a SPSR. My instinct tells me I should set the T bit if the entry point is in Thumb, but I can't find any information about this particular point. That's why I'm wondering if the special `movs pc, lr` can do it for me, if `lr` lsb is set

Comment: Ah, right - somehow I managed to skim over the crucial "entry point" detail. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with initial entry to a lower exception level is that it's not actually any different from the normal case - sure, you haven't actually *taken* an exception, but in order to "return" you simply make things look exactly as if you had.

The LR on exception entry is a straight copy of the PC at the time (minus any preferred return address offset) thus the lsb would never be set - interworking only applies to branches, and exception entry/return is not a branch. If you'd taken an exception whilst executing Thumb code, the LR value would be the real halfword-aligned instruction address, and SPSR.T would be set, so that's the state you need to construct.

Comment: Do you think I have to "clean" bit[0] of the return address ? From the ARM ARM pseudo code (see BranchWritePC), it seems that bit[0] is never actually read and always set to 0 in these instructions.

Comment: I'd clear it to be safe. A misaligned PC is generally unpredictable, so relying on an obscure corner of the v7 architecture (which crucially _doesn't_ apply to older versions) for the sake of saving one instruction is just needlessly unclear, IMO. Besides, if saving one instruction was _that_ important, you could just as easily do the return itself with `bics pc, lr, #1`. Except don't do that, since it's mad. And deprecated in v7. Don't tell anyone I even thought of it...